# Try to return list of bills

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, model, fastapi, pydantic

New to fast API, not able to find where I am doing wrong

Here is my router -

```
@router.get('/{user_id}/salesbill', response_model=list[schemas.ShowSalesBill], status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
def get_all_salesbills(user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    objs = db.query(bill_model.SalesBillModel).filter(bill_model.SalesBillModel.user_id==user_id)
    print(objs, "=================")
    return objs
```

Here is my schemas --

```
class BillBase(BaseModel):
    bill_no: int
    amount: int
    about: str



class ShowSalesBill(BillBase):
    id: int
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Here is my model -

```
class SalesBillModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "salesbill"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    bill_no = Column(Integer, index=True)
    amount = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    about = Column(String(50), nullable=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete='CASCADE'))

    user = relationship("User", back_populates="salesbills")
```

So, I am trying to get all the bills added by the user but getting an error

> pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for ShowSalesBill
> response
> value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)

Getting this error

```
SELECT salesbill.id AS salesbill_id, salesbill.bill_no AS salesbill_bill_no, salesbill.amount AS salesbill_amount, salesbill.about AS salesbill_about, salesbill.user_id AS salesbill_user_id 
FROM salesbill 
WHERE salesbill.user_id = ? =================
INFO:     127.0.0.1:47410 - "GET /1/salesbill HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mdhv/fastapi/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 419, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
```

Comment: updated plz check getting an error, I think there is an issue in query

Comment: can you try and add `.all()` `db.query(bill_model.SalesBillModel).filter(bill_model.SalesBillModel.user_id==user_id).all()`

Answer (score 1):

to understand the error : the response model you are putting in requires a **List**

of **schemas.ShowSalesBill** and you are not returning the same as expected.

I suggest you add id to the BillBase

```
class BillBase(BaseModel):
    id : int
    bill_no: int
    amount: int
    about: str
```

then you create a pedantic model that have a column with a list of BillBase:

```
 class ShowSalesBill(BaseModel):
     bill_list: Optional[list[BillBase]] = []
     class Config:
         orm_mode = True
```

then your endpoint became like this

```
@router.get('/{user_id}/salesbill', response_model=schemas.ShowSalesBill, status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    def get_all_salesbills(user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

        objs = db.query(bill_model.SalesBillModel).filter(bill_model.SalesBillModel.user_id==user_id).all()
        return schemas.ShowSalesBill(
          bill_list=[schemas.BillBase(**bill.__dict__) for bill in objs]    
)
```

I hope it helps!